# syncfusion.PDFviewer printing blank page after creating setup

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have to print existing pdf.
I am using window application c#.
I have install nugget - Syncfusion.PdfViewer.Windows (23.1.36)
I also have license.
When I run application through VS 2019 - printing pdf is working properly.
But It is printing blank page after installing setup of that win application.

Below is the code:

> ```
> using Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PdfViewer;
> ```

```
        try
        {
            PdfViewerControl viewer = new PdfViewerControl();
            viewer.Load(path);

            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;
                dialog.AllowSomePages = true;
                dialog.AllowCurrentPage = true;
                viewer.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings = dialog.PrinterSettings;
                dialog.Document = viewer.PrintDocument;
               string PrinterName = dialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                dialog.Document.Print();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Please suggest me what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.
Just give administrator permission in app.manifest.